# Move the transaction to a separate method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have several methods for working with the database: find/update/delete. They use a lot of the same type of code with a transaction, how can I put part of the code with a transaction in a separate method?

```
public List<Car> getAllCars() {

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            List<Car> cars = session.createQuery("from Car", Car.class)
                    .getResultList();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return cars;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            if (session != null) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return List.of();
        }
    }
public void updateCar(Car car, Long id) {

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Car updatableCar = session.get(Car.class, id);
            if (updatableCar == null) {
                throw  new NoSuchElementException("No such car in table");
            }
//            updatableCar.setModel(car.getModel());
//            updatableCar.setPrice(car.getPrice());
//            updatableCar.setInsuranceExpirationDate(car.getInsuranceExpirationDate());
            UpdateField updateField = new UpdateField();
            updateField.updFields(updatableCar, car);
            session.persist(updatableCar);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (session != null) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public void deleteCar(Long id) {

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Car deletableCar = session.get(Car.class, id);
            if (deletableCar == null) {
                throw  new NoSuchElementException("No such car in table");
            }
            session.remove(deletableCar);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (session != null) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I was thinking of making a method that returns a generic, but I have methods with type void

Comment: one method returns List<Car>, the second Optional, and the third void

Comment: Apart for the exception "handling" (that you're actually not really handling, just printing the stack trace), the code already seems pretty concise as is, it's not because few lines look alike that you need to force a refactoring in (especially if the refactoring would cause the code to become more unreadable).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import java.util.function.Function;
  ...
public <T> T work(Function<Session, T> f) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        T result = f.apply(session);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return List.of();
    }

}

public List<Car> getAllCars() {
    return work(session -> session.createQuery("from Car", Car.class).getResultList());
}

public void updateCar(Car car, Long id) {
    return work(session -> {
        Car updatableCar = session.get(Car.class, id);
        if (updatableCar == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such car in table");
        }
        UpdateField updateField = new UpdateField();
        updateField.updFields(updatableCar, car);
        session.persist(updatableCar);
    });
}

public void deleteCar(Long id) {
    return work(session -> {
        Car deletableCar = session.get(Car.class, id);
        if (deletableCar == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such car in table");
        }
        session.remove(deletableCar);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you. made through functional and consumer

Comment: If you think this was helpful, you can upvote.